# Limit number of connections per second in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am using `FutureRequestExecutionService` with `HttpClient` consisting of 20 connections and `ExecutorService` consisting of 20 executors.
Each executor is doing `HttpPost` request to *vk.com* API and returns `Future` with `List` of parsed objects.

However, I am getting error response from vk saying that I am doing too many requests per second (it is limited with 3 requests per second).

I have an idea how to rewrite requested functionality using Akka but is there any way to limit number of requests per second with Apache `HttpClient` or any other simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do input / output throttling at the byte per second basis by implementing custom [SocketImpl](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/SocketImpl.html) (for instance, done by Apache JMeter) or at the request per second basis by implementing custom [ManagedHttpClientConnection](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nice possible solution might be `RateLimiter` from Guava.